# Как вернуть статичный экземпляр в конструкторе?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть ли такая возможность? Я создаю атрибут и хочу, чтобы при создании экземпляра возвращался статичный экземпляр (чтобы для каждого объекта, к которому применен атрибут, не создавался отдельный экземпляр атрибута).

То есть в этом случае

```
[MyAttr]
class MyClass{ }
```

для класса не должен создаваться новый экземпляр MyAttrAttribute, а вместо этого должен передаваться уже созданный (статичный).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Конструктор на то и конструктор, что конструирует новый объект.

Возможно, в вашем случае решением будет сделать конструктор приватными, и создавать объект через статический метод (или какая-нибудь другая реализация паттерна «Фабрика»).

Comment: приватный конструктор не позволяет использовать атрибут. Жаль. Ну да ладно, обойдусь. (

Comment: @iRumba: Ну да, если это атрибут, то трюк не прокатит.